# Combining two indexOf and regex in to one

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following code that splits a combination of names on either the word `and` or the `&` ampersand:

```
    var name = 'Ron & Peggy Sue'; //or 'Ron and Peggy Sue';

    if ( name.indexOf('&') > -1 ){
        names = name.split(/ & /g);
    }

    if ( name.toLowerCase().indexOf(' and ') > -1 ) {
        names = name.split(/ and /gi);
    }
```

Its returns an array of names like:

```
names = ['Ron', 'Peggy Sue']; //regardless of `&` or `and` separator
```

I was trying to combine these two conditions into one, but the results were not what I wanted. I know there must be a better way. How can the above code be improved?

Answer (score 6):

You were almost there. You can use pipe (`a|b`) to designate the regex to look for both `a` **and** `b`. With that knowledge your split is as easy as:

```
var name = 'Ron & Peggy Sue and Darin Douglass';
names = name.split(/\s(?:and|&)\s/ig);
```

**EDIT:** The syntax `(?:...)` is whats called [non-capturing parens](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512471/non-capturing-group). These match the regex provided as '...' but it does not remember the matches. The problem with the simple `/\s(and|&)\s/ig/` was that the words `and` and `&` would be matched. This new syntax 'matches' them but does not remember (i.e. report) them. Thanks to @cbojar for the pointer.

Also, there is no need to check for either delimiter in `name`. If none exist it will simply return a single-element array with `name` as its element.

Comment: Totally nit-picking, but rather than repeat the spaces surrounding the two words, I'd say `/ (and|&) /ig` - or `/\b(and|&)\b/ig`

Comment: Agreed. Thats a better solution in any case :D

Comment: The problem with using `(and|&)` is that it is captured: `["Ron & Peggy Sue ", "and", " Darin Douglass"]`

Comment: Yeah I found some problems with both suggested regexes. The issue is `\b` is only recognized on *word* boundries. You can see the defined boundries [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html). `&` must not be a 'word character'.

Comment: You could try with non-capturing parens  `(?:and|&)` and the whitespace delimiter `\w`.

Comment: Good points. Had forgotten that captures get included in the split

Comment: `\w` is a word delimiter, not a whitespace delimiter, afaik.